# Ejecutar algo después de una función con jquery

Tags: jquery, stripe

```
function crearToken()
{
   stripe.createToken(cardNumber).then(function(result) {
      if (result.token) {
         $("#token").val(result.token.id);
      } else {
        Swal.fire('Por favor verifica los datos de tu tarjeta', '', 'error');
      }
   });
}

function funcionSig()
{
   crearToken().then(function(){
                   
      if($("#token").val() != "")
      {                
         gastoEnvio();          
        
         $("#tab-carrito .nav-tabs li:eq(1)").removeClass("active");
         $("#tab-carrito #seccion2").removeClass("active");
         $("#tab-carrito .nav-tabs li:eq(2)").addClass("active");
         $("#tab-carrito #seccion3").addClass("active");
         $("#tab-carrito #seccion3").tab("show");
      }
   });
}
```

Tengo esas 2 funciones, la función `crearToken()` ejecuta una función de la api de stripe para crear un token y la función `funcionSig()` ejecuta la función `crearToken()` para crear el token y si el token es creado entonces debe avanzar al siguiente paso.

El problema es que si crea el token pero no ejecuta el código que deberia hacer una vez ejecutada la función `crearToken()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu problema es que tu función crearToken no es una promesa, por lo tanto no te resuelve, lo tendrías que cambiar a una promesa para que te funcione como lo tienes.

[Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise)

```
function crearToken() {
    //Genera y regresa una nueva promesa
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        stripe.createToken(cardNumber).then(function (result) {
            if (result.token) {
                $("#token").val(result.token.id);
                resolve(); // Resuelve la promesa // Puedes adjuntar resultado resolve('valor');
            } else {
                Swal.fire('Por favor verifica los datos de tu tarjeta', '', 'error');
                reject();// Rechaza la promesa(Puedes adjuntar un error) reject('error')
            }
        });
    });
}

function funcionSig() {
    crearToken().then(function () {

        if ($("#token").val() != "") {
            gastoEnvio();

            $("#tab-carrito .nav-tabs li:eq(1)").removeClass("active");
            $("#tab-carrito #seccion2").removeClass("active");
            $("#tab-carrito .nav-tabs li:eq(2)").addClass("active");
            $("#tab-carrito #seccion3").addClass("active");
            $("#tab-carrito #seccion3").tab("show");
        }
    });
}
```